# Tomcat server will not start up with a filter

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters

Here is the web.xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Projeto_joas</display-name>

<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/DiaDiaDev</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>


<servlet>
<display-name>FacesServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>


<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- <filter> -->

<!--<filter-name>FilterHibernate</filter-name> -->
<!--<filter-class>util.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter</filter-class> -->
<!--</filter> -->

<!--<filter-mapping> -->
<!-- <filter-name>FilterHibernate</filter-name> -->
<!--<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> -->

<!--</filter-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

The server runs just fine this way, if i remove the comments on the filter, it won't
start and will throw me those exceptions:

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]] 
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

and

> WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Projeto_joas]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
>   javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader

the Filter class:

```
package util.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import util.HibernateUtil;

public class ConexaoHibernateFilter implements Filter {

    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        this.sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    }




    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {

            this.sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
            this.sf.getCurrentSession().close();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            try {
                if (this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `util.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter` class.

Comment: I'm not 100% exactly sure why this filter makes your application deployment to fail but I'm sure this is a bad practice. What if a page executes a basic `find` that doesn't need a transaction? Also, the database transactions should be handled in service layer (Model from MVC), not in a filter (Controller from MVC).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , i commented every code inside the methods of the filter and the session factory attribute,the server ran, i uncommented the session factory attribute the error happened, are there any rules that prevent filters to have certain attributes?

Comment: oh, i've solved it, the server needs to know the classes used on the filter so i just needed to copy the hibernate-core-<version>.jar to the tomcat lib folder and the server ran.

Comment: ***What*** exception? But you should take good note of what @LuiggiMendoza says above. This whole thing is a bad idea.

Comment: @EJP there was no exception i just needed to put the whole hibernate library into the tomcat/lib folder, telling me to read what Luiggi Mendoza said and not give me a suggestion of how else to do in the session handling wont help me, i'm doing this because i'm reading this of a book, the book calls it session per view method it seems like it's not good, but the only other way i can think of is every DAO having a new SessionFactory and opening a new session for every CRUD operation, and for as bad as session per view might be is better than that.

Comment: It isn't a session per view: it's a transaction per view. I don't know about Hibernate but JDBC can do that automatically for each new Connection or indeed each operation, without any of this.

Answer (score -1):

For me also same error was coming. The mistake I did was I didn't add any body to destroy and init methods.
So for me it worked by simply added some print statement inside the body of the destroy and init method.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("Error 404 bad request");
        // chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroyed"); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("initilized"); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }
```